# How do I set min and max values on jQuery time spinner?

Tags: jquery, forms

<strike>I'm building a form and I'm looking to add a jQuery function to `<input type="date">` that wont allow the user to select a date in the past. If they do so an error will display and the form wont validate.</strike>

**UPDATE: Disabling date in the past was fixed with jQuery Datepicker**

<strike>I also have a question about `<input type="time">`. How can I make this field only show times between say 11:30 and 22:00?</strike>

All that's left to figure out now is how to set a **min time** and a **max time**, e.g. min 11:30 and max 21:45, as well as figuring out how to get **15 minutes increments** on the last two numbers. Anyone up for that challenge? =)

I`m fairly novice to jQuery, so any help is very much appreciated.

Please find an **UPDATED example of my code in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamchriswick/3BQLL/8/).**

Comment: i think you can better use the Jquery DateTimepicker it covers it to a date object and it is crossbrowser. type="date" is not working on IE or FF http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: You can use the `min` attr for the `input` like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3BQLL/1/), you can do something similar for the time. However i agree with Rickdep that you should use jquery DateTimepicker.

Comment: @Rickdep Thanks, I managed to fix it with jQuery Datepicker =)

Comment: @Wahtever Not sure how to do something similar for time...

Comment: UPDATE: I might be on to something now... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamchriswick/3BQLL/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get 15 minute increment in on the last two numbers make step value    60*15000
eg.

```
$.widget("ui.timespinner", $.ui.spinner, {
    options: {
        // seconds
        step: 60 * 15000,
        // hours
        page: 60,
        max: "9:45 PM",
        min: "11:30 AM"
    },

    _parse: function (value) {
        if (typeof value === "string") {
            // already a timestamp
            if (Number(value) == value) {
                return Number(value);
            }
            return +Globalize.parseDate(value);
        }
        return value;
    },

    _format: function (value) {
        return Globalize.format(new Date(value), "t");
    }
});
```

here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3BQLL/14/)

Comment: Thnx! :) Any idea how I can set a min time and a max time as well?

Comment: @Prodac i have updated fiddle for min and max time. in option object use min and max. see updated answer.